# VC++ system programming-memory allocation for global variables in continuous memory location

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management, linker

Can someone explain me how to store global structures in ram in contiguous memory locations?

I tried the below but it doesnt work..!

## pragma section("ramsec",read,write)

## pragma section("ramsec1",read,write)

```
__declspec(allocate("ramsec"))
__declspec(align(8)) 
StructABC_t a;
__declspec(allocate("ramsec"))
__declspec(align(8)) 
StructDA_t b;
```

i want the above a,b structure to be stored in ram next to each other!!???

Comment: If you want a contiguous block of memory, you have to allocate it whole with a single call to operator new[] or malloc() or similar. Multiple calls to these functions do not guarantee any contiguity of allocated blocks whatsoever. You may allocate a big block and then carve parts from it as needed.

Comment: but when you are doing a embedded project, you have linker description file,which can be used for this kind of purpose. Does VC++ also offer something similar..

Comment: are you talking about hardware kind of thing??

Comment: actually i trying to simulate hardware code behavior in VC++ environment..

Comment: then better use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554460(v=vs.85).aspx function.

Comment: Hi I tried as explained in the below link, except for they were trying for functions, i am trying for global structures..still doesnt work any ideashttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192871/how-to-refer-to-the-start-of-a-user-defined-segment-in-a-visual-studio-project/16837206#16837206